# Get an URL hidden in HTML code with JSoup

Tags: java, url, href, jsoup

I have a piece of HTML code of a web page (library thing) like:

```
    <div class="qelcontent" id="4ed0e0ba4f1b16.47984984" style="display:block;"> 
<div class="description"><h4 class="first"><b>Amazon.com Product Description</b>
(<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0860783227" rel="nofollow noreferrer">ISBN 0860783227</a>, Hardcover)</h4>
```

I want to get the absolute URL from an `href` attribute.  I tried:

```
selector = document.select(".first .a[href]");
```

But it returned `null`.  How can I get the value?

Comment: well i tried exactly what i write above and as a result i got null.. There was nothing to found.. nothing to match with that selector..

Comment: Please provide the URL of the page.

Answer (score 0):

This solves this specific problem.. not sure if it will work with your entire dataset.

```
    String html = "<div class=\"qelcontent\" id=\"4ed0e0ba4f1b16.47984984\" style=\"display:block;\">" + 
    "<div class=\"description\"><h4 class=\"first\"><b>Amazon.com Product Description</b>" +
    "(<a href=\"http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0860783227\">ISBN 0860783227</a>, Hardcover)</h4>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    System.out.println(doc.select(".first").select("a").attr("href"));
```